# Using concatenation and a passed parameter to loop through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, parameter-passing, concatenation

```
var Animals = {
    "Europe": { "weasel.jpg": "squeak", "cow.jpg": "moo"},
    "Africa": { "lion.jpg": "roar", "gazelle.jpg": "bark"},         
};

function region(a){
    var b = "Animals."+a;
    for(var index in b) {
        var target = document.getElementById('div1');
        var newnode = document.createElement('img');
        newnode.src = index;
        target.appendChild(newnode)
    }
}
```

RELEVANT HTML

```
<li onclick="europe('Europe')">Europe</li>
```

Goal: on the click of the Europe `<li>`, pass the word Europe into my region function where it is then concatenated to produce Animals.Europe

This is in order to identify an array within the object structure at the top using the `for(var index in Animals.Europe)` loop. Why is the concatenation which produces Animals.Europe not treated in the same way as if I had typed this out?

In addition, you can see that I have used arrays to store an image source and description for different animals. Using my limited coding knowledge this was all I could think of. Is there an easier way to store image/description data in order to produce in HTML?

Comment: Did you mean `onclick="region('Europe')"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the europe property using the following

```
Animals[a]
```

Also you're calling a "europe" function when you should be calling "region"

You're not storing animals in arrays here, but in objects with the image names as keys. Usually you'll want to use relevant names as keys. For example if you want arrays of animals for each continent

```
var Animals = {
    "Europe": [{ 
      imageSrc: "weasel.jpg",
      cry: "squeak"
    },{
      imageSrc: "cow.jpg",
      cry: "moo"
    }],
    "Africa": [{
      imageSrc: "lion.jpg",
      cry: "roar"
    },{
      imageSrc: "gazelle.jpg",
      cry: "bark"
    }]         
};
```

Now Animals['Europe'] gives an array of objects, where you could eventually store other properties. So if b is an array your loop will now look like:

```
var b = Animals['Europe'];

for(var i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var target = document.getElementById('div1');
    var newnode = document.createElement('img');
    var animalData = b[i];   // The array item is now an object
    newnode.src = animalData.imageSrc;
    target.appendChild(newnode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, very much appreciated. I've not experimented with arrays/objects too much.. the reason I set the keys as the image names was so i could produce images from each continent was so i could loop through using *** for(var index in Animals.Europe) {  *** and then use the index variable from each run through the loop to create an img element using *** var newnode = document.createElement('img');
newnode.src = index; *** If I used the example above, how would I loop through the imageSrc properties to extract the .jpg data?

Comment: You'll get the hang of it :) I edited my reply with a loop example. It really depends if you are going to use the animal's cry, or add more details about each animals. If all you'll ever store is the image names, just have each continent give an array of image names.

Answer (score 1):

"Animals." + a is just a string value, e.g. "Animals.Europe", which is not the same thing as Animals.Europe.  If you change the first line to `var b = Animals[a];`, you should be all set.

Edit: and as elclanrs pointed out, it should be `region('Europe')`, not `europe('Europe')`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the concatenation which produces Animals.Europe not treated in the same way as if i had typed this out?

In this case the variable `b` is just a string ("Animals.Europe"), which is treated like any other string (i.e. a list of characters). This means that when you attempt to loop through it (`for(index in b)`) you will be looping over a simple list of characters.

What you can do instead is use the square brace notation of accessing an objects properties. This means you can instead write `var b = Animals[a]`, retrieving attribute `a` from Animals. You can read more about working with objects in this way [on this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)